# Go compiler undefined method

Tags: go, compiler-errors

I am getting a compiler error "w.Write undefined (type rest.ResponseWriter has no field or method Write)"

I created a bare bones test file and have the same problem:

```
package server

import (
        "github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest"
)

func WriteTest(w rest.ResponseWriter) {
        var bs []byte
        w.Write(bs)
}
```

The method that the compiler says is not defined is definitely in the [rest package](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/blob/master/rest/response.go#L92).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rest.ReponseWriter type has no Write, it has the following methods:

```
Header
WriteJson
EncodeJson
WriteHeader
```

However, it says [in the comments](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/blob/master/rest/response.go) that http.ResponseWriter methods are available by type assertion.  So you should be able to write the following:

```
package server

import (
        "github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest"
        "net/http"
)

func WriteTest(w rest.ResponseWriter) {
        var bs []byte
        w.(http.ResponseWriter).Write(bs)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Write` is defined on `responseWriter`. Note the lowercase `r`.